# Applescript broken in iTunes 11

Tags: macos, applescript, itunes

I found this AppleScript from http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/apple-tv-not-showing-descriptions/ that obviously worked in iTunes previously, but does not seem to work in iTunes 11.

```
tell application "iTunes"
 set myshows to selection
 repeat with eachshow in selection
  set desc to description of eachshow
  set long description of eachshow to desc
 end repeat
end tell
```

Does anybody know how to make this work again? It doesn't have to set the shows to selection, it can be all TV Shows in my library. I also wan't to run the same script on all Movies in my library.

Comment: What's not working?  I stepped through the code here with iTunes 11 and it copies the `description` property to the `long description` property without an error.

Comment: It does work!. If I change the text in the description field so it is different from the long description field. Then run the script. The description field text is what shows up in the long description field. So whats not working for you

Comment: I can confirm that this seems to be working correctly from my side as well. What exactly is the error you're getting ?